# How do I remove Chrome Apps

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, chrome-app

I know it says I'm supposed to be able to drag-and-drop the apps to the lower right corner and the apps will be removed.  That doesn't work.

It also says I should be able to right-click on the app, and there should be an option to **delete** or **uninstall** the app.  That is not on the menu when I right-click.

Is there a way to remove the apps elsewhere?  Neither of these two options works.

Oh ya ... running Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Comment: Which apps specify? If you've installed any stray toolbars (or similar), sometimes they add extensions to Chrome and lock them (some antivirus software are known to do this). Check `Add or remove programs` in the Control Panel and see if the they are listed there.

Comment: Don't add the solution to your question (or change the title to include "resolved"). If you have found a solution yourself, write a new answer on your question and then "accept" it.

Answer (score 1):

When right click on Chrome Apps (on New tab) you should get something like below:
[image: Remove from Chrome (Right click)]

And simply choose "Remove from Chrome"

By Click And Drag to the trash bin on the corner it should look like this:

[image]

The only App you can't remove are app that are default to Chrome which is "Store"

What App are you trying to remove?

Answer (score 0):

OP says:

> ***RESOLVED*** -- Un-install Chrome.  Reinstall, and the option to remove is back.

(Will happily remove this if/when OP writes his own answer.)